# скачет меню при наведении

Tags: css

видимо из-за паддингов при наведнии курсора скачет меню, как исправить это поведение меню?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
  padding: 22px 0px;
}

.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-container a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 20px 6px;
  margin-right: 63px;
}

.header-container .nav_link:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5aa;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .nav-menu{
    display: none;
  }
  .header-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .btn {
    display: none;
  }
}

.btn {
  z-index: 1;
  /* display: block; */
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #223;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.btn span,
.btn span::before,
.btn span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; margin-top: -1px;
  left: 50%; margin-left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.btn span::before,
.btn span::after {
  content: "";
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn span::before {
   transform: translateY(-7px);
}

.btn span::after {
   transform: translateY(7px);
}

.btn_active span {
  height: 0;
}

.btn_active span::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.btn_active span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* адаптивный нав бар */

.nav-menu_active {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start ;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 140px;
    padding-top: 65px;
    background: #223;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-menu_active .nav_link {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}


.nav-menu_active a:last-child {border-bottom: none;}

.nav-menu_active .nav_link:hover {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="100px" height="100px">
      </div>

        <a class="btn" href="#"><span></span></a>

            <nav class="nav-menu">
              <a class="nav_link"href="#">Блог</a>
              <a class="nav_link"href="#">О нас</a>
              <a class="nav_link"href="#">Главная</a>
              <a class="nav_link"href="#">Контакты</a>
            </nav>
     </div>
  </header>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        $(this).toggleClass('btn_active');
        $('.nav-menu').toggleClass('nav-menu_active');

      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: да. я забыл добавить о том, какое именно меню

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно поиграть с [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::after) или [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::before) :

```
/*
.nav-menu_active a:last-child {border-bottom: none;}
*/

.nav-menu_active .nav_link:hover {
  background: transparent;
  /*border: 1px solid white;*/
}

.nav-menu_active .nav_link {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-menu_active .nav_link:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: '';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  padding: 22px 0px;
}

.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-container a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 20px 6px;
  margin-right: 63px;
}

.header-container .nav_link:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5aa;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .nav-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .btn {
    display: none;
  }
}

.btn {
  z-index: 1;
  /* display: block; */
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #223;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.btn span,
.btn span::before,
.btn span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.btn span::before,
.btn span::after {
  content: "";
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn span::before {
  transform: translateY(-7px);
}

.btn span::after {
  transform: translateY(7px);
}

.btn_active span {
  height: 0;
}

.btn_active span::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.btn_active span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


/* адаптивный нав бар */

.nav-menu_active {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  padding-top: 65px;
  background: #223;
  border-radius: 25px;
  z-index: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-menu_active .nav_link {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}


/*
.nav-menu_active a:last-child {border-bottom: none;}
*/

.nav-menu_active .nav_link:hover {
  background: transparent;
  /*border: 1px solid white;*/
}

.nav-menu_active .nav_link {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-menu_active .nav_link:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="100px" height="100px">
      </div>

      <a class="btn" href="#"><span></span></a>

      <nav class="nav-menu">
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">Блог</a>
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">О нас</a>
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">Главная</a>
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault;
      $(this).toggleClass('btn_active');
      $('.nav-menu').toggleClass('nav-menu_active');

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

как вариант ( но не самый лучший)

```
.nav-menu_active .nav_link {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    //добавить
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

//убрать
.nav-menu_active a:last-child {border-bottom: none;}
```

Comment: работает, но почему не самый лучший?

Comment: @СотниЛичностей Вам нужно было в nav добавить общий контейнер, тогда не прыгало бы.